# Java - How to accurately get the ip address of the requestor

Tags: java, servlets, java-8, servlet-3.0

We are currently working on a program to catch automated attacks (brute force, DoS etc.). We wanted to have a 2nd level handling of it next to Firewall handling. We already developed a logic but the problem is how to accurately get the ip address of the requestor.

The request passes through the ff:

Request -> firewall -> web server -> mobile app server -> app server for APIs(where our web service is deployed).

Its also possible the request can be behind a proxy. With this is it still possible to get the correct ip address of the requestor? so it could be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

You web server maybe nginx, consider [Using the Forwarded header](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/).But you can only get the ip of the proxy server when the request behind a proxy, because it limited by the tcp/ip layer mechanism.